# Table so wide, the width should be 750px in the heading

Tags: html, function, html-table, row, multiple-columns

Here is the problem I got. Please see the attached screen capture.

Wide Column A:
[image: Wide Column A]

I want the SPRINKLER DUTY REQUIREMENT/S to be 750px same as the ANNUBAR FLOW TEST RESULTS.
And also please check the screenshot. My inches of mercury column is so wide. I will only adding number 0 to 34 for that.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Chart Nine Body -->
<div class="row g-0" id="chartNine" style="display:none;">
    <h4 class="card-title">TOWN'S MAIN FED - SPRINKLER ANNUBAR FLOW TEST</h4>
    <table id="dataTable2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SPRINKLER DUTY REQUIREMENT/S</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label></label>
                    <input type="text6" value="0" />
                    <label> L/MIN @ </label>
                    <input type="text6" value="0" />
                    <label> KPA </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick="addTable('dataTable2');">+</button>
    <br>
    <table id="dataTable3">
        <!--<table>-->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ANNUBAR FLOW TEST RESULTS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: gray">
                    INCHES OF MERCURY
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: gray">
                     MODEL 20T, SINGLE MOUNT 3/8" Dia Probe Size
                     <select>
                         <option disabled selected style="font-weight: bold">SELECT AN OPTION</option>
                         <option>20T DN50</option>
                         <option>20T DN65</option>
                         <option>20T DN80</option>
                         <option>20T DN90</option>
                         <option>20T DN100</option>
                         <option>20T DN125</option>
                         <option>20T DN150</option>
                     </select>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: gray">
                     kPa
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="background-color: gray">
            <label>
                INCHES OF MERCURY
            </label>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color: gray">
            <label>MODEL 20T, SINGLE MOUNT 3/8" Dia Probe Size
                     <select>
                         <option disabled selected style="font-weight: bold">SELECT AN OPTION</option>
                         <option>20T DN50</option>
                         <option>20T DN65</option>
                         <option>20T DN80</option>
                         <option>20T DN90</option>
                         <option>20T DN100</option>
                         <option>20T DN125</option>
                         <option>20T DN150</option>
                     </select></label>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color: gray">
            <label>kPa</label>
        </td>
        </tr>
                <td>
            <label for="range1">
                0
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>TEST</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text6" value="0" />
        </td>
                </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 750px;">
        <canvas id="nineChart" style="display:none;"></canvas>
    </div>
```

And here is my function:

```
#dataTable2 {
        counter-reset: nRow;
    }

    #dataTable2 thead th {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: .4em 0;
        background-color: gray;
        min-width: 34rem;
        width: 290px;
    }
    
    #dataTable3 thead th {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: .4em 0;
        background-color: gray;
        min-width: 34rem;
        width: 290px;
    }
    
    #dataTable3 div:first-child
    {
        width:30%;
    }
    
    /*#dataTable3 tbody tr td label:nth-child(1) {*/
    /*    display: inline-block;*/
    /*    width: 2em;*/
    /*    text-align: center;*/
    /*}*/

    #dataTable2 tbody tr td label:nth-child(1) {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 2em;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #dataTable2 tbody tr td label:nth-child(1)::before {
        counter-increment: nRow;
        content: counter(nRow);
    }
```

I really need your help. It would benefit me, thank you so much!

Comment: Hello M. Eriksson, this is also a table. I am doing multiple tables at the same time that will populate a chart.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Did you try to insert a fixed width?

```html
  <!-- Chart Nine Body -->
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 750px;">SPRINKLER DUTY REQUIREMENT/S</th>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Hello Flebedev99, it worked. I tried it on <th>ANNUBAR FLOW TEST RESULTS</th> it seems not to work

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: Hey jabaa, this is the answer to my question. flebedev99 is right

Comment: You should change this to "Use a fixed width on the HTML element" or something similar; to explain to others how and why your code solves the problem.